# Excel VBA - Creating a macro that inserts the active sheet name inside another sheet cell's forumula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with two sheets inside my workbook. The "active sheet" and my "Vendor Top Sheet". My "active sheet" can be one of many duplicate deal memos that I prepare for my vendors, so it could be one of many different sheets inside the workbook. On all these deal memos, I would like to have a button that executes a macro to do the following:

In "Vendor Top Sheet" on the next available cell in the row specified, I want to insert a formula making it equal to cell B8 of the current active sheet. I haven't been able to figure out how to get a VBA reference to the "Active Sheet" inside the standard excel formula. Here's my code so far:

```
Sheets("VENDOR TOP SHEET").Range("A38")
                          .End(xlUp)
                          .Offset(0, 11)
                          .Value = FormulaR1C1 
                                 = "='[ " & ActiveSheet.Name & " ]'!B8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you including the square brackets and spaces here?

Just try using this instead, assuming `ActiveSheet` is within the same workbook:

```
Sheets("VENDOR TOP SHEET").Range("A38").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11).Formula = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!B8"
```

Comment: @BrandonStockwell: Great to hear. If you click the checkbox to the left, it will let future viewers know that this is the correct solution. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheets("VENDOR TOP SHEET").Range("A38").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11).Formula = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!B8"
```